# How to cast double into string in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, orm

I have hql query like following:

`select  sellingPrice, cast(sellingPrice as string)  from Inventory`

But after casting, it's giving unexpected results like the following:

> 6.31          6.3099999999999996
>
> 6.37          6.3700000000000001
>
> 6.38          6.3799999999999999
>
> 6.38          6.3799999999999999

Why is this query casting `6.31` AS `6.30999999999996`.

Please advise.

Comment: You can use BigDecimal instead of double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to return a string for the second arguemnt then round the value before cast as follows:

```
select sellingPrice, 
       cast(((abs(sellingPrice) * 100 + 0.5)/100.0 * sign(sellingPrice)) as string) 
from Inventoryfloor
```

Read this for basic explanation -> https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2474138

Comment: AFTER ADDING ONE BRACKET AFTER CAST KEYWORD IT WORKS FOR ME                                                                                           cast(((abs(sellingPrice) * 100 + 0.5)/100.0 * sign(sellingPrice)) as string)